# In Avatar (The Last Airbender, Legend of Korra), was there ever an Ultimate Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Has there ever a certain avatar who was able to bend irregular things like metal, plants, lightning, and if so, could you possibly have an "Ultimate" Avatar that was able to bend every element including the weird ones. I've tried to do research on this but I haven't been able to find much.

Comment: Do you intend the scope to include only the two TV series?

Comment: Re metal in particular: Metalbending was invented by Toph during *The Last Airbender*, so you probably won't find avatars older than Aang who can metalbend, unless Toph was actually rediscovering a technique that had already been known in some forgotten era.

Comment: Mendeleev can [bend all 118+ elements](https://xkcd.com/965/).

Answer (score 12):

All the bendings that you've mentioned in your question are actually subtypes of one of the *main* bendings.

*Plantbending* is actually waterbending, the waterbender in this case bends the water within the plants.

*Lightningbending* is a subtype of bending that comes from firebending.

*Metalbending* is also a subtype of bending, but this one comes from earthbending.

*Lavabending* [is first regarded](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Avatar_Extras_(Book_Two:_Earth)#.22The_Avatar_State.22) as a combination of firebending and earthbending (look for item 112), but in TLOK it was shown as a subtype of earthbending.

The only Avatar that has shown the ability to metalbend is Korra, but this makes sense as only her and Aang had the chance to learn how to metalbend as this bending was discovered recently by Toph Beifong.

There's no evidence of an Avatar performing *plantbending* and/or *lightiningbending*, but there are at least two events that indicates that they can, as yourself said, perform *weird* types of bending:

1. Avatar Roku is able to lavabend (during the eruption of the volcano on his home island)
2. Avatar Korra is able to metalbend (Suyin Beifong teaches her how to metalbend)

In these two examples, we see two different Avatars performing *weird* bending techniques.

Avatars are regarded as being more skilfull and powerful than most benders, and if we take into consideration that they have special training for several years (only Aang didn't because of the context he lived in) we can assume that they are able to bend *weird* elements, which in the world of Avatar are actually subtypes of the main bending techniques.

There's no in-canon answer, as you said, we have no mention of an Avatar that could bend all of these subtypes of bending techniques, thus we can only speculate, but I believe it's safe to assume that a skilled and well trained Avatar can perform lightningbending, plantbending, among other subtypes of bending such as bloodbend.

Comment: I believe Hama invented bloodbending, so similar to metalbending, only Aang and Korra would have the ability to learn it. And since it's both unethical and eventually illegal, I don't think either would

Answer (score 5):

In *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, Aang was able to **successfully bend all of the basic four elements**: Air, water, earth and fire, respectively.
Something new that Aang did was to invent energybending, with which he seized the power of Ozai, Lord of Fire and the father of Zuko who became one of the best friends of Aang.

One is also able to see the same procedure in *The Legend of Korra*. There is a scene showing a past memory where Aang uses energybending to remove the bending power of a bloodbender.

Korra also successfully bends all the basic elements, plus she was able to bend, more or less, metal.

Hence **there is no avatar** that **was able to bend all the elements you mentioned**.

Comment: What Aang does to Ozai and the bloodbender is called "energybending".

Comment: @F1Krazy thank you, do not hesitate to edit the answer.

Comment: Aang did not "invent" energy bending. It was taught to him by his ancestral connections to past avatars via that original turtle guardian thing.

Comment: Then edit the answer, @TylerH